# Kannel - efficiency & bulk sms support

Tags: kannel, bulksms

These are the things I want know.

1.Is there a way to send bulk messages using kannel?

2.We can use fakesmsc in the following way, but it sends the same sms to same number, multiple times

```
fakesmsc -r port -i interval -m count "from to text your message"
```

Is there a way to send same sms using fakesmsc with different recipient numbers?
For eg, using a file with recipient numbers

```
fakesmsc -r 13010 -i 0.1 -m 100 "66456 /root/recipient.number.list text test message"
```

3.Is there a way to send sms using cgi-bin url with a time interval?
for ex, like this url, is there a parameter like interval that we can say the **interval**?

```
cgi-bin/sendsms?from=66456&to=111+222+333+444+555&text=message&interval=0.1
```

4.Is there any other way to do this

5.What is the maximum incoming rate and outgoing rate  (msg/sec) in Kannel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to send bulk messages using kannel?

Yes. You can use **mtbatch** command line utility from Kannel package. Just run mtbatch without arguments to see help message.

> Is there a way to send same sms using fakesmsc with different recipient numbers?

Yes. It is possible to randomize messages in fakesmsc (see **-z** parameter description in **fakesmsc -h** output).

Example from **fakesmsc -h** output:

```
fakesmsc -z 7 -m 1000 "123<rand> 345<rand> text nop <rand>
```

> Is there a way to send sms using cgi-bin url with a time interval?

No. You only can limit throughput on certain SMSC connection.

> Is there any other way to do this?

Yes. You can use external software that will handle outgoing bandwidth. For example you can use **mtbatch -d seconds** to send messages with proper rate.

> What is the maximum incoming rate and outgoing rate (msg/sec) in Kannel?

It depends on too many factors (hardware, networking, used protocols, configuration).

In practice I have reached 2,500 msg/sec rate on SMPP connection.